# .Net keep data on the object through out the application

Tags: c#

I'm using visual studio 2013 and working on a asp web project. Since i'm new to the development, i have this issue.

The scenario is this. when a user login in, since this is a web service based project, apart from the username and passwords the service will return some values. so i have to keep those values such as user name, address, age throughout the application until he log out.

I have tried to keep the values using like this,

```
public class CONSTANTS
{
    public static String address;
    public static String age;
    public static String tele; 
}
```

so that i can use classname.address likewise. but when i do this, if two people try to access at the same time, it's not working and i know this is not a valid method. please help me on this. how should i implement this, it would be better if i have a small sample code. thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use RESTful APIs? i.e. authorize the user with each call

Comment: Since I'm new to the concept, I don't know it

Comment: I think it's worth the time to know it. if you want a quick solution though, you can have a dictionary of the User object you want and save state to it Dictionary<Username, User> . but I recommend going with the RESTful solution, it's simply authenticating the user through a token sent with every API call, and you can save the users data in a local cache for fast retrieval instead of calling DB for every API call

Comment: Exactly, what i want is as you said, "and you can save the users data in a local cache" - i need this. how to save user data in ln class

Comment: The application is going to be used by multiple users. if i use my method, it's not going to work.

Comment: .Net offers MemoryCahce https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx have a look at it and pay attention to the delete policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this using session Variable as Session Remains different for all Users who Login in your Web Application.

You can store value in Session in your Login buttons click Event as.

```
 Session["username"]=xyz;
 Session["pass"]=*****;
 Session["age"]=20;
```

etc...

and you can also retrive values from session whenever Required as.

```
  string uname=Convert.Tostring(Session["username"]);
  string pass=Convert.Tostring(Session["pass"]);
```

etc..

make sure you need to explicitly cast value in your Desired type as Session return in Object form.

Comment: That's a good idea. But there are more variables are there. So I thought it's not a good solution. My whole point is I want to use variables of an object in another class for multiple users

Comment: you can also store dictionary of Users variable in session but make sure @ time of Retrival you need to cast it in desired Type.